# Restrict users from using admin section in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, authorization

I am using membership in asp.net mvc 2 and i want to restrict users from using the admin section , Currently all the users can access the admin section by using their credentials, I used [Authorise] for all the http get and post request for that , but how can restrict everyone apart from admin & some users with certain privileges , I have got table in db asp_net Roles which have 2 role names : Admin and user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this ...

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Comment: but i want some users to use the admin section

Comment: @dknaack is correct. The users that you want to access the section need to be in the admin role. They will be authorized and all other users will not